# Make a dependent loop independent

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, gpu

Is there any technique which can transform a dependent loop (I mean a loop in which the k-th iteration depends on the result of the previous iteration(s)) to an independent one making it a candidate for parallelization? It would be important because I have such a loop and I want to migrate it to the GPU. If it is a help, the loop is a `for` loop with a-priori known iteration count.

```
for (int n = 1; n <= nmax; n++) {
    t = nhVal;
    Nv = gfft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1) * kv)), 2));
    a = E2 * v + QNv;
    Na = gfft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1) * ka)), 2));
    b = E2 * v + QNa;
    Nb = gfft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1) * kb)), 2));
    c = E2 * a + Q * (2 * Nb - Nv);
    Nc = gfft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1) * kc)), 2));
    v = Ev + Nvf1 + 2 * (Na + Nb) * f2 + Ncf3;
    if (mod(n, 100) == 0)
        printf("n = %d\n", n);
    if (mod(n, nplt) == 0) {
        plotIdx++;
        u = real(ifft(v));
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int n = 1; n <= nmax; n++){
  t = n*hVal;
  Nv = g*fft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1)*k*v)), 2));
  a = E2*v + Q*Nv;
  Na = g*fft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1)*k*a)), 2));
  b = E2*v + Q*Na;
  Nb = g*fft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1)*k*b)), 2));
  c = E2*a + Q*(2 * Nb - Nv);
  Nc = g*fft(pow(real(ifft(tile(i, N, 1)*k*c)), 2));
  v = E*v + Nv*f1 + 2 * (Na + Nb)*f2 + Nc*f3;
  if (mod(n, 100) == 0)
   printf("n = %d\n", n);
  if (mod(n, nplt) == 0)
  {
   plotIdx++;
   u = real(ifft(v));
  }
 }`
There are several FFTs and IFFTs but on a CPU only one thread enters to the loop to calculate them.

Comment: How can I format that way? Formatting has lost during paste. I used `.

Comment: @ChristopherColumbus Look up. Refresh. I did it for you

Comment: Your problem is kinda transforming a recursive algorithm in an iterative algorithm. You have to figure out how to transform `Un = f(Un-1)` into `Un = f(n)`. Only you can do that, we don't know the specifics of your algorithm

Comment: Mathematically it is recursive but computationally it is iterative since there is no recursive function call in it, am I right?